# Can I diagonalize a 80000*80000 matrix using lapack in fortran 95? How much ram it will need?

Tags: matrix, fortran, lapack, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to diagonalise a sparse matrix(N*N) where N is 80000. I want to have the eigen values and eigen vectors of this matrix. I will be using a fortran which includes Lapack_dsyev for this. How much time and RAM it will consume?

I have a cluster having 197GB RAM is it sufficient for the diagonalization?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Is your program distributed in memory or for one node? How much memory does one node have? Do you use double precision? How much sparse the matrix? Please note that LAPACK DSYEV is for **dense** matrices and is not optimized for sparse matrices. There are dedicated sparse matrix libraries. You can easily compute how much the matrix will need, one element is typically 8 bytes. 8*80000*8000 = 51.2 x10^9 ~ 50 GB.

Comment: And you will need at least double Vladimir's estimate as you need the evecs, and probably a bit more. But, importantly is the memory in n your "cluster" all available to a single process, or is it distributed? We've diagonalized appreciably bigger matrices than you require, but that is with Scalapack on a distributed memory machine typically using many hundreds of processes

Comment: It depends on your problem, but you may not need all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of your matrix. And keeping it sparse would save a great amount of memory and computations. Arnoldi methods could be a practical solution to your problem. Could you take a look at ARPACK ? https://github.com/opencollab/arpack-ng This fortran library is behind scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/arpack.html